# Suddenly no access to mysql table in Dreamfactory

Tags: mysql, http-status-code-403, user-roles, dreamfactory

## The Problem

I am building an application with Dreamfactory 2.7.0. It is deployed with bitnami/docker on my local machine (MacOS).

There are some tables and some relations between them. POSTing and GETting data has been no problem up until now.

The error message `Access Forbidden. You do not have enough privileges to access this resource.` usually comes up when the requested resource has not yet been made accessible in the roles config.

This time however, access is clearly granted and it has worked before.

The roles config states:
`mysql / _table/table_i_need_data_from / GET|POST / API.`

There is only one user role and the user has that role. All the other tables can still be queried.

I can neither GET nor POST to `table_i_need_data_from`.

## I have tried:

1. Rebooting
2. Reloading the page (Dreamfactory admin panel) (there seems to be a cache problem, sometimes)
3. Changing the access settings / changing them back
4. Delete the access settings, add them again
5. Made sure the table name is written correctly (in the code) (copy/paste)
6. Made sure the entire request is written correctly (in the code) (generated)
7. Flushed system cache (from DF admin)

## What I did before

I tried to add virtual relationships. The dropdowns were all empty so I could not set them up. I don't know if the 403 already happened before that or later. But it was around the same time.

## The Question

What must I do to get the access working again?

## Edit

When I use the API Docs from the Admin panel, the same request works fine.

Answer (score 0):

There was custom API script, which did nothing but exist.
When I deleted the script, removed the ACL settings and added them again, it worked.

There seems to be a correlation between custom API scripts and the ACL evaluation.
Maybe someone has a little insight to what could cause this. Other than that, the problem is gone and the question therefore moot.